# Regular expressions - python

Tags: python, regex

i am new to regular expressions and developed this to find out if idno has values from 0 to 9 in the first nine characters and V, v, X or x as the last. Is the syntax correct because it sends an error requesting two args.
Another problem is that it should be only 10 characters long. I used a separate code to validate that but can I integrate it into this too?

```
if len(idno) is 10:
    if re.match("[0-9]{9}[VvXx],idno") == true:
        print "Valid"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have more wrong there than right, I'm afraid. Note the following:

- You should really compare integers by *equality* (`== 10`) not *identity* (`is 10`) - CPython interns small integers, so your current code will work, but that's an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on;
- If you add `$` (end of string) to the end the regular expression will only match strings ten characters long, making the `len` check unnecessary anyway;
- The quotes are in the wrong place, so you're passing a single string to `re.match`, rather than the pattern and the name you want to try to match it in - the comma and `idno` are all part of the `pattern` parameter;
- `'true' != 'True'`: Python is case-sensitive, and the booleans start with capital letters;
- `re.match` returns either an `SRE_Match` object or `None`, neither of which `== True`. However, it's pretty awkward to write `== True` even where you're only getting `True` or `False`, and you can use the fact that `Match` is truth-y and `None` is false-y to write the much neater `if some_thing:` rather than `if some_thing == True:`; and
- Regular expressions already have a case covering `[0-9]`, you can just use `\d` (**d**igit).

Your code should therefore be:

```
if re.match(r'\d{9}[VvXx]$', idno):
          # ^ note 'raw' string, to avoid escaping the backslash
    print "Valid"
```

You could simplify further using the `re.IGNORECASE` flag and making the group for the last character `[vx]`. A few examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> for test in ('123456789x', '123456789a', '123abc456x', '123456789xa'):
    print test, re.match(r'\d{9}[vx]$', test, re.I)
                                            # ^ shorter version of IGNORECASE


123456789x <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10041e308>  # valid
123456789a None  # wrong final letter
123abc456x None  # non-digits in first nine characters
123456789xa None  # start matches but ends with additional character
```

Comment: You forget the dollar. `r'\d{9}[vx]$'`

Comment: Thanx people, much appreciated :)